# Can't load file from device with multiple external memory areas

Tags: java, android, file, loading, device

I have an App that compiles against SDK 1.5 for compatibility reasons, I would like to try and keep it that way. I am allowing user's to save images to the external memory, which at the time I was sure was always an SD-card. I want the images (files) to stay even if the user uninstall the App, otherwise I could have saved to internal memory and App would delete upon uninstall.

Up until now I have had no problems loading images from my test devices, but now I got an Toshiba Thrive tablet that besides internal DDR ram, have 8GB internal Flash memory and an SD-Card slot. My App saves the images fine on the Toshiba declaring storage location like this:

```
// Note: First I create a folder for my App - Not shown here, but it works fine

file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "MyApp" + File.separator + "test.png);
```

On the Toshiba tablet it always saves with the above method on the internal flash device, which is fine, however using same declaration the same file won't load, which I find really strange.

I load using this very simple method;

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "MyApp" + File.separator + "test.png);

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
```

And then display bitmap

I have not had a previous need to set any file permissions, other that if I compile against SDK 1.6 or higher I need in the manifest this

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Even so I thought that was only to allow writing.

Comment: Please show how you're loading the file. What are the permissions set for the created file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry people, I had to change my code handling rotation as values for orientation was different, the way I used to do it, from my other devices, plus the tablet was connected via USB to PC which had locked access to folder - duh :(